# Power BI Web Service - Comma's and cards

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm having trouble with Power BI Web Service.

I designed some cards on Power BI Desktop :

[image: :]

But when I publish it to my web workspace Power BI Web Service won't read numbers with commas or points correctly.

[image]

I have tried the "data type" option and  "Change type with local" option on edit query but none of these seem to work.

also, Power BI service is deleting some "data labels" and "totals" on my graphics that are showing ok on desktop.

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely related to the localization settings in the service.

One option is to explicitly format your measures using FORMAT rather than relying on Power BI to make its best guess.

For example,

```
Porcentaje = FORMAT ( ..., "0.0%" )
```